# How to update records in datagridview on button click?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb

i bind the data in DataGridView between two dates using datetimepicker control.
now i want to update all records on button click,when i edit the records in DataGridView.
This is the code which is displaying the records in DataGridView.

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select i.billno,i.idate,i.cname,i.address,i.mob,p.brand_name,p.category,p.price,i.quantity,p.gstper_product,i.sub_total,t.grand_total from (customer_invoice_details i inner join product p on i.pid=p.pid) inner join totalamt t on i.billno=t.billno where i.idate between @date1 and @date2", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTime1.Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", datetimeto.Value.ToString());
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

so Help me how can i do this...

Comment: What happens if you use `da.Update(dt)`? Of course you will have to widen the scope of the `da` variable so that you can use it in your button_click method.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue. To update datagrid I have used refresh method.

```
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Also at one point it workt for me by resetting data binding to data grid by

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Please add comment how you eddit the data that is not update. Maybe the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

how you are going to update the records mention on it.
am giving you a sample try on this.

**Get Selected Row Values From DataGridView Into TextBoxes**

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

        ' get the index of the selected datagridview row
        index = e.RowIndex
        Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow

   ' show data from the selected row to textboxes
        selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
        TextBoxID.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxFN.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxLN.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxAGE.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()

    End Sub
```

**update the datagridview selected row using textbox**

```
 Private Sub btn_Update_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If txt_Name.Text <> "" AndAlso txt_State.Text <> "" Then
        cmd = New SqlCommand("update tbl_Record set Name=@name,State=@state where ID=@id", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully")
        con.Close()
        DisplayData()
        ClearData()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update")
    End If
End Sub
```